# Query data from ADX event hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure-eventhub, adx

Can you please refer simple code example to read data from a table in azure data explorer event hub using .net application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, do you want to read the data from ADX or from an eventhub?

ADX stores it's data on a proprietary internal format, you can only query it using KQL.